# estou com duvida nesse codigo

Tags: java

```
public class Idades{
 

    
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        System .out.println ("Entre com a quantidade de idades");
        int idades = scan.nextInt();
        //int = scan. nextInt();

        int idade;
        int soma = 0;
        
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i < idades; i++){

            System.out .println ("Entre com a idade da pessoa " + (i+1));
            idade = scan.nextInt();

            soma += idade;
        }

        double media = soma / idades;

        System.out .println ("Media de idade: + media");

        if (media >= 0 && media <=25) {
            System.out . println ("jovem");  
        }else if (media >= 26 && media <=60){
        System.out . println ("Adulto");                               
        } else if (media > 60){
            System.out . println ("idosa");   


        }

        
    



       
        
            
        

        


    }
}




}
```

Está dando esse erro:

```
/Idades.java:64: error: class, interface, or enum expected } ^ 1 error
```

Comment: Aparentemente, o código está recebendo uma variável do tipo errado. Você pode dizer qual é a linha do erro? Isso aumentará as chances de você receber a ajuda que espera.

Comment: `soma` deveria ser `double`. Como é `int`, o resultado de `soma / idades` é um `int` também, e o valor é arredondado. Teste com duas idades: 7 e 8 - e veja que a média acaba sendo 7 (e não 7,5) pois uma divisão entre dois `int`'s é arredondado antes de ser convertido para `double`. O certo é a `soma` ser `double`, assim funciona corretamente. Quanto aos `if`'s, dá para melhorar também, veja: https://ideone.com/7yV3Q8

Answer (score 0):

Observa-se alguns pontos no seu código em que, provavelmente, estão gerando erros:

- Primeiro ponto é o fato de ter uma `{` sobrando no seu código, presente na última linha.
- Em segundo lugar, é necessário especificar o tipo de variável quando declarada (nas versões mais novas do java é possível utilizar `var`, mas acredito que por legibilidade, neste caso, a solução apresentada a seguir seja melhor). Assim, no trecho em que é colocado `scan = new Scanner(System.in);`, seria substituído por `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);`. Consequentemente, é necessário colocar o import do Scanner, o qual é: `import java.util.Scanner;`
- Além disso, recomendo uma correta identação do seu código, visando sua legibilidade. A seguir colocarei seu código identado.

  ```
   class Idades {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.println("Entre com a quantidade de idades");
         int idades = scan.nextInt();
         //int = scan. nextInt();

         int idade;
         int soma = 0;


         for (int i = 0; i < idades; i++) {

            System.out.println("Entre com a idade da pessoa " + (i + 1));
            idade = scan.nextInt();

            soma += idade;
         }

         double media = soma / idades;

         System.out.println("Media de idade: + media");

         if (media >= 0 && media <= 25) {
            System.out.println("jovem");
         } else if (media >= 26 && media <= 60) {
            System.out.println("Adulto");
         } else if (media > 60) {
            System.out.println("idosa");
         }
      }
   }
  ```

Comment: Só pra reforçar: `System.out.println("Media de idade: + media");` isso está errado, deveria ser `System.out.println("Media de idade: " + media);`